# paragraph "<p>" padding not applied

Tags: css, padding, paragraph

The following three pieces of code behave exactly the same:

```
<p {padding: 0 15 0 15}>  A paragraph of text here...  </p>

<p> A paragraph of text here... </p>

<p style="padding: 0 15 0 15">  A paragraph of text here...  </p>
```

How do I get the paragraph indented on both sides? (I tried 15px instead of 15 (EDIT - but only on the first two), I also tried separating the numbers with commas, like an example I found on Google.)

The above code is in a div which is in the body, no other divs or tables, etc. are involved.

The div is defined:

```
<div style="background-color: white; color: black; overflow:auto">
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 15px instead of 15 is recommended to make the solution (using "style") work with all browsers. I've seen certain IE-versions ignore values without a unit. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#units - you're only save to omit the unit when the value is "0".

Comment: In addition to the good answers below, may i suggest firefox and the firebug plugin as being very useful when figuring out your html styling issues.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

15? 15 what? Have you considered using *units*?

```
<p style="padding: 0 15px">foo</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed both the "style=" and the "px"

Comment: I'd recommend using em instead of px because it's more cross-browser compliant.  ie. <p style="padding: 0 1em;">bar</p>

Comment: @jwhat Using em instead of px isn't precisely a cross-browser compliance issue. It's more about prioritizing precise design (px) vs text-resizing (em).  All browsers these days interpret the units correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
<p {padding: 0 15 0 15}>  A paragraph of text here...  </p>
```

to:

```
<p style="padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px">  A paragraph of text here...  </p>
```

Comment: I thought it would work, but it didn't.  I added the above code to my problem description.

Comment: This example is incorrect, you still need a unit like 15px or 1em.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have a previous line like this:

```
p { display: inline }
```

This **CSS disable** the use of padding.