# How to get padding to show up to the left of the contents?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, padding, user-experience

Here is the prototype I am trying to to implement 
[image]

Here is what I have so far - [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lasred/37bj5g3q/1/) [image]

The highlighted part is what I am currently working on. I am trying to get some space between the paragraph contents and the components to the left of it(Profile 6, Profile 7)

I recognized this space as [padding](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/05/mastering-css-coding-getting-started/#CSS-Basics1) because it involves space between inner contents and the border. Because this is regards to the left side of the paragraph, I used  [padding-left](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-left.asp).  
From my JFiddle,

```
#content{
   padding-left:10px;
}
```

Where content is the id of the paragraph(I checked it). However when I applied the style, nothing happened....

Does anyone know what the issue is? I saw one another thread on problems with [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426449/paragraph-p-padding-not-applied) but the issue there was that units was never specified. Here, I made sure to specify padding units(in px)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p id="content"><h3>...</h3></p>` is not valid HTML. change the `<p>` to `<div>`.

Updated - http://jsfiddle.net/37bj5g3q/2/

Comment: Yeah that didn't come to mind but I read this as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p . It's confusing because a paragraph is  a block element.

Comment: Read more - [Putting <div> inside <p> is adding an extra <p>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p)

Comment: Yep, those two posts are explaining the same thing. I think the <p> tag is special, as it stands for *paragraph*, obviously a heading shouldn't be inside a paragraph.